# Generics and parameter implementing two interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface, delegates, type-constraints

I'm trying to create a simple in-memory bus implementation where the constructor can take a pipeline as parameter, i.e.

```
public Bus(Action<IMessage, Action<IMessage>> eventPipeline)
{
    _eventPipeline = eventPipeline;
}
```

where `IMessage` is an empty interface (used to have a common interface for `IEvent` and `ICommand`).

I then have a single decorator that I want to be part of the pipeline (i.e. it should be called each time we publish an event onto the bus, before the event handlers subscribing to that particular event are being called):

```
public class HttpAuditDecorator<T> : IDecorator<T> where T : IAuditable, IMessage
{
    private ILogger _logger = Logging.Logger;

    public void Handle(T msg, Action<IMessage> next)
    {
        ...
        next(msg);
    }
}
```

Here `IAuditable` is another interface that doesn't have anything to do with `IMessage`. And `IDecorator` is

```
public interface IDecorator<T> where T : IMessage
{
    void Handle(T msg, Action<IMessage> next);
}
```

The problem arises when trying to instantiate the bus:

```
public static Bus Bootstrap()
{
    Instance = new Bus((@event, next) => new HttpAuditDecorator<T>().Handle((IAuditable)@event, next));
    ...
}
```

The problem is what to write in `T`'s place. I'd like to somehow tell that `T` implements `IAuditable` and `IMessage`. Of course, one could create a new interface that inherits from both, but I would very much prefer to avoid this.

Comment: Shouldn't `T` be something specific? Why is there a generic argument on `HttpAuditDecorator` anyway?

Comment: Thanks for taking a stab at this! :)
T in `Bootstrap()` should definitely be something else. That's exactly my question.
HttpAuditDecorator has a generic argument instead of using `IMessage`, because I could think of situations where I want to specify that a particular decorator only works for either `IEvent` or `ICommand`.